# Avoid escaping in xml

Tags: actionscript-3, jsfl

I read a xml file contains

```
<![CDATA[<property id="SubClass"></property>]]>
```

When I write back into file , it will become:

```
&lt;property id="SubClass"&gt;&lt;/property&gt;
```

How can I avoid it and write back the original string ? I mean just write back:

```
<![CDATA[<property id="SubClass"></property>]]>
```

P.S.

I used `alert()` to display it before write to file.It's all right but without .Like:

```
<property id="SubClass"></property>
```

The writing back function is following:

```
var xmlObj = <![CDATA[<property id="SubClass"></property>]]>;
FLfile.write(path, xmlObj);//unescape() is useless there.
```

FLfile is an object in jsfl(FlashJavaScript).

Comment: Have you tried using unescape() on your string?

Comment: @CreativeMagic I have used it and don't work.

Comment: Please include the code how you write the XML file

Comment: @CreativeMagic Already included

Comment: Hm, you write the file as an XML object. Not a bad approach, but why not just write it as string and have the file extension .XML, then the parser won't try to change your string

Comment: @CreativeMagic I have tried it but nothing changed.I think the changing taken place in the FLfile Object

Comment: @CreativeMagic I think you're right.I change the xmlObj to String after all operations and write back to the file . And result is all right!You can write down it in the Answer,thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run into a problem where the parser is replacing special symbols of XML syntax, save the XML as a String opposed to XML object to preserve the data.